# Dagger dependency cycle between Presenter and Callback

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, circular-dependency, dagger

I have a PresenterModule where I instantiate the presenter, passing as parameter a conteiner of callbacks. All these callbacks are instantiated, in CallbacksModule, passingas parameter the presenter, because need to communicate back to the presenters the results of the call.

**The problem is that it is creating a dagger injection dependency cycle.** How may I solve it? Thanks.

```
@Module
class CallbacksModule {


@Provides
fun provideProcessCallbacks(call1: RegistrationCallback,
                                  call2: SignatureStartCallback,
                                  call3: SignatureRegistrationCallback): GenerationProcessCallbacks {
    return GenerationProcessCallbacks(call1, call2, call3)
}

@Provides
fun provideRegistrationCallback(presenter: StepPresenterImpl): RegistrationCallback {
    return RegistrationCallback(presenter)
}

@Provides
fun provideSignatureStartCallback(presenter: StepPresenterImpl): SignatureStartCallback {
    return SignatureStartCallback(presenter)
}

@Provides
fun provideSignatureRegistrationCallback(presenter: StepPresenterImpl): SignatureRegistrationCallback {
        return SignatureRegistrationCallback(presenter)
    }
}
```

presenter module:

```
@Module
class PresenterModule {

@Provides
fun provideStepProcessPresenter(callbacks: GenerationProcessCallbacks): StepPresenterImpl {
    return StepPresenterImpl(callbacks)
}
```

callbacks code:

```
override fun onSuccess(registrationResponse: RegistrationRequestResponseModel?, useCaseIdentifier: String?) {
        presenter?.onRegistered(registrationResponse)
    }

override fun onUnexpectedError(t: Throwable?, useCaseIdentifier: String?) {
    if (t != null && t is InvalidSessionException) {
        return presenter?.showErrorOnView(t.code)
    }

}
```

presenter code:

```
override fun onRegistered(registrationResponse: RegistrationRequestResponseModel?) {
    signatureStartUseCase
            .identifier(SignatureStartUseCase::class.simpleName)
            .responseOnUI(false)
            .execute(registrationResponse,  callbacks.signatureStartCallback)
}
```

For the first two callbacks, they call another usecase. And for the last callback, it shows data on view.

Comment: There is lazy injection in Dagger which should alleviate the issue.

Comment: @TheLibrarian any example?

Comment: callbacks: Lazy<GenerationProcessCallbacks>. Though generally cycle dependency is code smell. Posting some of the callbacks and presenter could help solve the cycle in other way.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need Dagger to create those callbacks?

Comment: Well, not specially, actually they, in theory,will be only used there, in that presenter implementation. @TheLibrarian

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments, you might not need the callbacks to be injected. Injection is typically pretty inexpensive, in terms of code and runtime cost, but it's not applicable for all cases. You may only want to inject in cases where it is useful to you to inject other dependencies or reconfigure the class through Dagger, though tests are a perfectly valid reason to want that reconfiguration.

The root of the dependency cycle problem, though, is that you are asking for a  GenerationProcessCallbacks *instance* and Presenter *instance* at the same time, so Dagger can't create either one before the other. Instead, you can inject a [Provider](http://javax-inject.github.io/javax-inject/api/javax/inject/Provider.html) (`Provider<GenerationProcessCallbacks>`) or [Lazy](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/Lazy.html) (`Lazy<GenerationProcessCallbacks>`), for which you only call `get()` *outside* the Presenter's constructor. This lets you create the Presenter first, because Dagger knows that you will have a Presenter instance with which to construct the GenerationProcessCallbacks. For that you'll also want to scope the component and Presenter with [`@Singleton`](http://javax-inject.github.io/javax-inject/api/javax/inject/Singleton.html) (or some other scope annotation) so the same Presenter instance that creates the callbacks is also responsible for their generation; otherwise, Dagger will create an outer presenter that depends on the callbacks, and the callbacks will depend on one or more distinct Presenter instances compared to the outer one.